# REST/Jersey Rererence implementation

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb

I need to know the purpose of the use of **MessageBodyReader** and **MessageBodyWriter** in rest web service, why and when should I use them ? The conversion form java to **xml** and vice versa using **jaxb**, isn't it done automatically with rest web service(for example jersey RI) ?

Waiting for you response
Best regards

Comment: Too lazy to read [about it](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)?

Comment: I have just read this article, and I'm not lazy, don't say it again ! this article start directly to talk about the use of MessageBodyReader and MessageBodyWriter and it deos not tell why and what's the purpose of them ? my question is why to use them ???? and it is not about how, please read my question carefully......

Comment: I actually did not tell you **are** lazy, I put a question mark. Instead of asking here why don't you just use some search engines? Could be also very helpful.

Comment: @ArthurEirich I am not familiar with jaxb and from that same documentation link you provided, it's not trivial to answer this question, since they refer that "a best way how to learn about entity providers is to walk through an example of writing one" which implies you have to code them or read their code in order to understand the classes. If you already read it and understood these classes and their methods, feel free to answer the question.

Comment: I tested an example with MessageBodyReader and MessageBodyWriter, my inquiry is about  the purpose ?  I don't know why they are used.

Comment: @TheBlack See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipze/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, this doesn't explain everything about the purpose of their usage, though .